# MASM console window creation troubles (maybe my stack frame??)

Tags: winapi, assembly, stack, x86-64, masm

I'm having trouble with the following code snippet. 
I'm compiling an asm file with a c++ file using visual studio express 2012.

I've tried debugging calculating the addresses of the stack pointers and memory locations (still learning assembly obviously), but can't find a fault. (As I'm new it's probably something obvious, but not obvious enough).  The asm part is just a function called from the c++ file that is supposed to open a console window and print something in it.  The `SetConsoleTitleA` works fine, it trips on the `Writefile` function. Here is the error itself :

```
First-chance exception at 0x00007FF8551A5B48 (KernelBase.dll) in
Troy2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 

0x00007FF700000000.
    Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8551A5B48 (KernelBase.dll) in Troy2.exe: 
0xC0000005: 
    Access violation writing location 0x00007FF700000000.
```

And the code is here :

```
extrn GetStdHandle: PROC
extrn WriteFile: PROC
extrn AllocConsole: PROC
extrn FreeConsole: PROC
extrn SetConsoleTitleA: PROC
extrn SetConsoleCursorPosition: PROC
extrn Sleep: PROC
extrn ExitProcess: PROC
extrn MessageBoxA:PROC

.data
consoletitle db 'Console', 0
prompt db 'Oronco-> ', 0
handle dd ?

.code

myfunction proc
    call AllocConsole
    sub rsp, 20h
    lea rcx, consoletitle
    call SetConsoleTitleA
    add rsp, 20h

    sub rsp, 20h
    mov rcx, -11
    call GetStdHandle
    add rsp, 20h

    mov handle, eax

    sub rsp, 28h
    lea rcx, handle
    lea rdx, prompt
    mov r8, SIZEOF prompt
    mov r9, 0
    mov dword ptr [rsp + 20h], 0
    call WriteFile
    add rsp, 28h
    mov rcx, 2000
    call Sleep

    Call ExitProcess
myfunction endp
End
```

Comment: Did you tried to trace the code through a debugger? Are you sure that the access violation is during `WriteFile` call (because it is hard to see the corresponding code for virtual adress `0x00007FF700000000`.

Comment: I used the "step into" commands in the debugger, ive tried placing other instructions before writefile but it still fails. I take it my stack looks good so far and problem is not as easy as it sounds ?

Comment: Im trying to figure out how to post more info with the code tags

Comment: You're doing the stack allocation wrong. The `sub rsp, 28h` instruction misaligns the stack and you need to reserve 32 bytes at the bottom of the stack for all a function calls, even those that don't take arguments. The simple fix for all of this is to only do the stack allocation once. Add an `sub rsp, 30h` statement as the first instruction of your code, and delete all the `sub rsp` and `add rsp` instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mov dword ptr [rsp + 20h], 0
```

is wrong. The last parameter has the type `LPOVERLAPPED`, which is here a 64-bit pointer. Change the line to

```
mov qword ptr [rsp + 20h], 0
```

Also,

```
lea rcx, handle
```

is wrong. `WriteFile` expects a value, not an address (pointer). Change it to

```
mov ecx, handle
```